# several layers using the same sprite sheet

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Pardon me if this sounds a bit trivial. In my game several of the layer classes use the same sprite sheet. I want to avoid declaring the same batch nodes in every layer class. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. A node can have only one parent. If you create a batch node and add it to one layer, you can't add it to another. If you pass the reference to the batch node around that would work but it makes having layers pretty pointless because the sprites will be children of the layer the batch node is added to.

You could instead use a single batch node and group the sprites by adding "layer sprites" with an empty texture rect to the batch node, and then adding the actual sprites to the layer sprites.

To create a sprite with an empty texture use the initWithTexture:rect: method and use a CGRectZero. Alternatively in case this no longer works you can also use a very small rect and set the sprite's opacity to 0. Setting visible to NO may also work, depending on whether visibility is propagated in sprite batched sprites or not.